# jQuery full width slider loading for some time before running

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using jQuery full width slider [PlusSlider](http://css-plus.com/examples/plugins/PlusSlider/) on my [test website](http://selectinteriors.tangent-design.com/).

But the issue is the slider is loading for sometime before it starts to run. I am not able to find what is causing the slider to wait for 2-6 seconds before it runs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slider3').plusSlider({
            fullWidth: true,
            autoPlay: true, 
            displayTime: 5000, // The amount of time the slide waits before automatically moving on to the next one. This requires 'autoPlay: true'
            sliderType: 'slider' // Choose whether the carousel is a 'slider' or a 'fader'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If your talking about the dealy between the page loading and the first "movement" then look at the documentation regarding "displayTime".

Comment: Dom reday aprox. 3seconds with empty cache, displayTime 5 seconds, adds up to aprox. 8second before it starts ?

Comment: Your site throws an error in the JS console "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mCustomScrollbar' ". To debug this just add "debugger" somewhere and the JS console will pop up (if active)

Comment: yeh when go on website it loads for sometime , how can i get the image straight away

Comment: any ideas on how to aboid d loading time